# Coredump size different than process virtual memory space

Tags: macos, coredump, darwin, xnu

I'm working on OS X 10.11, and generated dump file in the following manner :

```
1. ulimit -c unlimited
2. kill -10 5228 (process pid)
```

and got dump file with the rolling attributes : `642M Jun 26 15:00 core.5228`

Right before that, I checked the process total memory space using `vmmap` command to try and estimate the expected dump size.

However, the estimation (238.7Mb) was much smaller than the actual size (642Mb).

Can this gap be explained ?

```
                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                  2048K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    4K        2 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
MALLOC metadata                    180K        6 
MALLOC_SMALL                      56.0M        4         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_SMALL (empty)              8192K        2         see MALLOC ZONE table below
MALLOC_TINY                       8192K        3         see MALLOC ZONE table below
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        2 
Stack                             8192K        2 
__DATA                            1512K       44 
__LINKEDIT                        90.9M        4 
__TEXT                            8336K       44 
shared memory                       12K        4 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            238.7M      110 

                                 VIRTUAL ALLOCATION      BYTES          REGION
MALLOC ZONE                         SIZE      COUNT  ALLOCATED  % FULL   COUNT
===========                      =======  =========  =========  ======  ======
DefaultMallocZone_0x100e42000      72.0M       7096       427K      0%       6
```

Answer (score 1):

coredump can, and does, filter the process memory. See the [core man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html):

> **Controlling which mappings are written to the core dump**
>
> Since kernel 2.6.23, the Linux-specific /proc/PID/coredump_filter file can be used to control which memory segments are written to the core dump file in the event that a core dump is performed for the process with the corresponding process ID.
>
> The value in the file is a bit mask of memory mapping types (see mmap(2)).  If a bit is set in the mask, then memory mappings of the corresponding type are dumped; otherwise they are not dumped.  The bits in this file have the following meanings:
>
> ```
>       bit 0  Dump anonymous private mappings.
>       bit 1  Dump anonymous shared mappings.
>       bit 2  Dump file-backed private mappings.
>       bit 3  Dump file-backed shared mappings.
>       bit 4 (since Linux 2.6.24)
>              Dump ELF headers.
>       bit 5 (since Linux 2.6.28)
>              Dump private huge pages.
>       bit 6 (since Linux 2.6.28)
>              Dump shared huge pages.
>       bit 7 (since Linux 4.4)
>              Dump private DAX pages.
>       bit 8 (since Linux 4.4)
>              Dump shared DAX pages.
> ```
>
> By default, the following bits are set: 0, 1, 4 (if the `CONFIG_CORE_DUMP_DEFAULT_ELF_HEADERS` kernel configuration option is enabled), and 5. This default can be modified at boot time using the coredump_filter boot option.

I assume OS X behaves similarly.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, but does any of the optional data represented by bits 0-8 adding memory that is not accounted in process virtual mapped memory acquired by `VmSize` field in `/proc/self/status` ?